# Jaybird 2.2.4 NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints

Tags: hibernate, jpa, firebird, jaybird

Using @Transactional(value ="erpJPA",propagation=Propagation.NESTED )
i have the exception

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: 
JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities
```

Doesn't firebird support Nested Transaction from version 1.5?

Comment: If it isn't implemented in the dialect, it isn't available, it could also mean it isn't supported in hibernate.

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using?

Comment: it was JPA 2.1i think